# GeoDjango - How to store measurement data

Tags: python, django, geodjango, measurement

Assume I have recorded the following values during a bike trip. One such dataset has been recorded every 5 seconds:

```
timestamp, longitute, latitude, pulse rate, pedal frequency
```

What is the best way to store them in a GeoDjango application? I thought about using a model similar to the following.

```python
class Measurement(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField()

class MeasurementPoint(models.Model):
    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurement)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    pulse = models.IntegerField()
    pedal = models.IntegerField()
```

This works and I can query the measurement points. But now I want to display the bike trip on a map, so I have to convert the individual points to a LineString. How is this done? And how would it bit possible to use different colors to highlight for example the pulse rate with different colors?

Answer (score 0):

Probably should store it into a file field as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212009/django-postgres-large-time-series) for timeseries data. The other option is to use a JSON field in Postgres.