# Django + Influxdb

Tags: django, django-models, influxdb

I have tseries data that has been stored in influxdb, I would like to serve this data through a web API and therefore are considering Django framework and its REST API framework as a solution.

At the moment, there is [no known support for Influxdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/) on Django framework, however I have seen someone imply successful creation of this stack in a discussion thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212009/django-postgres-large-time-series/32641215#32641215).

Any clear comments or thoughts on how this can be achieved would be appreciated, particularly how to integrate influxdb into the Django framework.

Comment: @user2205880 would you be in a position to expound on how to go about achieving the jango/influxdb connection and making the Django models work with the data from influx  as you mentioned in the linked discussion thread ?

Comment: Do you already have `django + influxdb ORM`

Comment: @gao.xiangyang not to my knowledge

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Django and InfluxDB together in Docker. First, create a project and app.

```
mkdir django-influxdb-example
cd django-influxdb-example
django-admin startproject project
cd project
django-admin startapp app
cd ..
```

Create a virtual environment and install django, postgres and [influxdb](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python).

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install django psycopg2 influxdb
pip install --upgrade pip
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Right now, my requirements look like,

```
certifi==2018.8.24
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.1.1
idna==2.7
influxdb==5.2.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.5
requests==2.19.1
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.23
```

Create a `Dockerfile`,

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
    && apk add libpq postgresql-dev \
    && apk add build-base

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY project ./
```

Create a `docker-compose.yml` file,

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres

  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/web/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - influxdb
    links:
      - influxdb

  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "8086:8086"
```

I added the following to my Django `settings.py`,

```
INFLUXDB_HOST = 'influxdb'
INFLUXDB_PORT = 8086
INFLUXDB_USERNAME = None
INFLUXDB_PASSWORD = None
INFLUXDB_DATABASE = 'example'
INFLUXDB_TIMEOUT = 10
```

At this point, you could try to build the whole thing and see if it comes up,

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run web python3 manage.py makemigrations
docker-compose run web python3 manage.py migrate
docker-compose up
```

If you go to localhost:8000, then you should see the default Django splash page. If you open an interactive Python session on the web container, you should be able to access InfluxDB through the Python [influxdb](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python) module,

```
docker-compose run web python3
Starting django-influxdb-example_db_1 ... done
Starting django-influxdb-example_influxdb_1 ... done
Python 3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 02:19:14)
[GCC 6.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
>>> client = InfluxDBClient('influxdb', 8086)
>>> client.get_list_database()
[{'name': '_internal'}]
>>> client.create_database('example')
>>> client.get_list_database()
[{'name': '_internal'}, {'name': 'example'}]
```

Now everything is connected and running, you can focus on writing to code to create databases, and add points. I looked through the code for [django-influxdb-metrics](https://github.com/bitlabstudio/django-influxdb-metrics) and found the code below, which I put in a `utils.py` file in my `app/` directory. This creates an influxdb client using the constants we defined earlier in the `settings.py` file.

```
from django.conf import settings

from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def get_influxdb_client():
    """Returns an ``InfluxDBClient`` instance."""
    client = InfluxDBClient(
    settings.INFLUXDB_HOST,
    settings.INFLUXDB_PORT,
    settings.INFLUXDB_USERNAME,
    settings.INFLUXDB_PASSWORD,
    settings.INFLUXDB_DATABASE,
    timeout=getattr(settings, 'INFLUXDB_TIMEOUT', 10),
    ssl=getattr(settings, 'INFLUXDB_SSL', False),
    verify_ssl=getattr(settings, 'INFLUXDB_VERIFY_SSL', False),
)
return client
```

Finally, from here, I can create databases, add points, and perform queries through the client.

Comment: It works when influx is started as an independent service. When I wrote the question, I was grappling with how to replace the underlying database used by Django for its models, perhaps a direction that was not necessary had I known about the concept of containerization. The solution makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: I see that this resets the connection with every request, do you have an idea how to use a persistent connection? This is out of scope but I am not sure it is worth a question of its own.